# Unable to set numbering to paragraph style in LibreOffice Writer

Tags: libreoffice-writer, numbering

I am editing `Heading 1` style wishing to set numbering, but can't due to the strange message

```
This option is disabled when chapter numbering is assigned to a paragraph styling.
```

How to enable?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to *Tools > Chapter Numbering*. By default, `Heading 1` is set to use the chapter numbering options described there.

[image: Chapter Numbering - Heading 1]

To get headings that look like "1.2.1 The Next Section" you can select `1 - 10` and set *Number* to "1, 2, 3, …"

If you do not want to use chapter numbering in this way (although I'm not sure what the use case would be for that), then set *Paragraph style* to `None` for Level 1. Then the *Numbering style* for style properties can be modified.